# Нужно определить значение переменной count после выполнения программы

Tags: javascript

```
let count = for (let i = 1; 1; < 10; i++) count = if (i % 2 === 0) { count++;
```

Как определить значение переменной count после выполнения программы ? Объясните пожалуйста , только начала изучать JavaScript

Comment: Для начала программу правильно запишите

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать два способа:

1. Вывод в консоль: `console.log(count);`
2. Вывод на экран: `alert(count);`

Лучше использовать второй, он будет нагляднее.

*(также Вы, в будущем, сможете изменять данные на странице в реальном времени, после выполнения функции - подробнее об этом написано в книгах, которые рекомендуется читать)*